# In Chrome, SignalR 2.1.1 hub client-to-hub method terminates connection early when hub code broadcasts to clients

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR 2.1.1 strongly-typed hub where the client is calling a server hub method and within that method a broadcast is sent to the clients (in my test case it is only the caller that is getting called).

The hub method has no return value (`async public Task Test()`).  From the server side, the hub method appears to throw no exceptions.  On the client side, I get `Error: Failed at parsing response: {"C":"d-4336366B-A,0|B,1|C,2|D,0|E,0","M":[{` and `Clearing hub invocation callbacks with error: Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received.`

It appears the connection is getting terminated before the response is sent completely.

The problem is happening in Chrome on Windows 7 but not in IE 11.

### Simplified Hub Class

```cs
public class MessengerHub : Hub<IMessengerClient>, IMessengerHub
{
    async Task IMessengerHub.TestActivityNotification()
    {
        ConnectionInfo info = _connectionInfo[_hub.Context.ConnectionId];

        Activity activity = new Activity
        {
            ActivityId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            ContactId = info.UserId,
            DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
            DeviceId = info.DeviceId,
            Kind = ActivityKind.Message,
            SubKind = ActivitySubKind.MessageSent
        };

        // This code is actually in another method, just simplifying for demo
        await Task task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // I thought the problem might be with the groups...
                //Clients.Group(userId.ToString()).OnActivity(activity);
                foreach (ConnectionInfo info in _connectionInfo.Values.Where(ci => ci.UserId == userId))
                {
                    Clients.Client(info.ConnectionId).OnActivity(activity);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

If I comment out the call to OnActivity above, the problem goes away.

### JavaScript initialization code

This is from the Razor page so note the Razor syntax.

```js
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SignalR Initialization
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$(function () {

    // ------------------------------------------
    // Set up the client side of the hub
    // ------------------------------------------
    var messengerHub = $.connection.messengerHub;
    var hub = $.connection.hub;

    radarMessenger.hub = messengerHub;
    radarMessenger.signalr = {
        stateConversion: {0: 'connecting', 1: 'connected', 2: 'reconnecting', 4: 'disconnected'}
    };

    messengerHub.client.onActivity = radarMessenger.onActivity;


    // ------------------------------------------
    // Connect to the hub
    // ------------------------------------------

    @{
            Activity context = SecurityUtils.GetContext();
        }
    hub.qs = {
        deviceId: '@context.DeviceId',
        userId: '@context.ContactId'
    };

    hub.logging = true;

    hub.starting(function() { 
        console.log("SignalR: Starting"); 
    });

    hub.received(function(data) {
        console.log("SignalR: Received: " + JSON.stringify(data)); 

    });

    hub.connectionSlow(function() { 
        console.log("SignalR: Connection slow"); 
    });

    hub.reconnecting(function() {
        console.log("SignalR: Reconnecting"); 
    });

    hub.stateChanged(function(data) {
        console.log("SignalR: State changed from " + 
            radarMessenger.signalr.stateConversion[data.oldState] + " to " + 
            radarMessenger.signalr.stateConversion[data.newState] ); 
    });

    hub.disconnected(function() { 
        console.log("SignalR: Disconnected"); 
    });

    hub.error(function (error) {
        console.log("SignalR: Error: " + error ); 
    });

    hub.start()
        .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + hub.id); })
        .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not Connect!'); });

    $("#TestActivityNotification").click(function () {
        console.log('TestActivityNotification');
        messengerHub.server.testActivityNotification()
            .done(function () {
                console.log("Called testActivityNotification successfully");
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                console.log("Error in testActivityNotification: " + error);
            });
    });
});
```

### Chrome dev console

```
SignalR: State changed from disconnected to connecting 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:397
SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'messengerhub'. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: Starting 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:380
SignalR: Negotiating with '/securemessaging/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.4&deviceId=a60aea91-1d79-4881-943d-1fbf3cb8ba4e&userId=2deb491a-c4f6-4f99-b653-aac65450c3db&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22messengerhub%22%7D%5D'. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'https://dev01.myradarconnect.com:13004/securemessaging/signalr/connect?tran…Uo10Wpetj&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22messengerhub%22%7D%5D&tid=7'. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: EventSource connected. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: serverSentEvents transport selected. Initiating start request. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332 and a connection lost timeout of 20000. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: State changed from connecting to connected 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:397
Now connected, connection ID=64188d16-5abe-4e67-9393-10eb59862f82 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:411
TestActivityNotification 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:415
SignalR: Invoking messengerhub.TestActivityNotification jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: Error: Error: Failed at parsing response: {"C":"d-4336366B-A,0|B,1|C,2|D,0|E,0","M":[{ 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:407
SignalR: Stopping connection. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: State changed from connected to disconnected 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:397
SignalR: EventSource calling close(). jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: Clearing hub invocation callbacks with error: Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received.. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
SignalR: messengerhub.TestActivityNotification failed to execute. Error: Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received. jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js:81
Error in testActivityNotification: Error: Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received. 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:421
SignalR: Disconnected 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:403
SignalR: Received: {"$id":"4","$type":"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubResponse, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core","I":"0"} 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:384
```

### Update 2014-09-24 Custom JsonSerializer

Based on the answer from @halter73, I am updating to say that I am indeed using custom JsonSerializerSettings.  I'll mess with those and update.  Here they are:

```cs
    private static void ConfigureJsonFormatter()
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
        jsonSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
        jsonSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        jsonSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
        jsonSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
        jsonSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(jsonSettings);
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);
    }
```

I am using Entity Framework and needed to tweak some of the JSON serialization settings to avoid some issues with entity serialization, in Web API, MVC, and SignalR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the following line in your log:

```
SignalR: Received: {"$id":"4","$type":"Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubResponse, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core","I":"0"} 105b20f2-2a6a-46da-83ae-35c32b82eba1?Archived=True:384
```

It looks like you are using a custom JsonSerializer. This can be problematic if you're not careful, because SignalR relies on some default behavior. For example, JSON payloads must be only one line to work with SignalR's [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) transport.

Chrome supports the [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) API required to use server-sent events, but IE does not. This is likely why you are only seeing the issue with Chrome.

Comment: I am using custom JsonSerializerSettings.  I've updated the question with specifics.  I'll go back and mess with those.  Do you have any references for what the expectation of JSON settings are?  I am using Entity Framework and needed to tweak some of the JSON serialization settings to avoid some issues with entity serialization, in Web API, MVC, and SignalR.

Comment: First thing I'll change is removing the Indent formatting option based on server-sent events needing one line.  I don't need the indenting; it's just been to help debugging.

Comment: Removing the Indent formatting on the JsonSerializerSettings fixed the problem.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

does not work - due to jquery version

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/signalr/jquery.signalR-2.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/Noc/NocDOCSIS/Scripts/script.noc.light.js"></script>
```

works - due to Jquery version

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.4/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/signalr/jquery.signalR-2.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/Areas/Noc/NocDOCSIS/Scripts/script.noc.light.js"></script>
```

[image]